# How do I align these two mirror-image objects?

Tags: transforms, mirror

I'm adapting another person's .stl file for my own purposes.  In the picture, you can see the left side of the gun, which I duplicated/mirrored successfully, but I need to position these two halves together to fuse them into a single object.  I understand how to merge them into a single mesh (Ctrl-J), but I don't know how to position them effectively so that they will merge without any gaps.

How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please following these steps:

- Delete half the model

[image]

- In Edit mode, from front/side view, select a vertice at the center of the model (where you want to merge the two halfs together).
- Press Shift+S > Cursor to Selected

[image]

- In Object mode, right click and select Set Origin> Origin to 3D Cursor

[image]

- Add a Mirror Modifier. On the Mirror Modifier, check the 'Clipping' checkbox
- (Optional): Hover your mouse over the Mirror Modifier and Press CTRL+A to apply it.

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help :)